# Can't get text with Beautifull Soup from between <p> </p>

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://habr.com/ru/hubs/gamedev/articles/" # Url to website

page = requests.get(URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
post = soup.find("article", class_="tm-articles-list__item") # Last post thah i need to parse 

discription = post.find_all('p')
for post_text in discription:       # Trying to separate the text 
    text = post_text.get_text()

print(text)
```

Getting this error:
File "d:\CODING\Projects\net N FV.py", line 14, in 
print(text)
^^^^
NameError: name 'text' is not defined.
Or
text that i dont need

On a website post's html code, that im parsing, looks like this:

```
<div class="article-formatted-body article-formatted-body article-formatted-body_version-2"> 
<p> 
"Сегодня первой игре из серии DOOM исполняется ровно 30 лет! Мы не могли обойти стороной это событие и в честь этого решили посмотреть, как же выглядит код этой легендарной игры спустя годы."
 </p>
<p></p> 
after:: 
</div>
```

Comment: `print(text)` is outside of the loop. The scope has changed and your python interpreter doesn't know where to look for `text`.

Comment: Sure, i changed it, and now i get nothing `PS D:\CODING\Projects>`

Comment: `soup.find` only returns one element, so there's nothing to iterate through.  Perhaps you meant `find_all`.

Comment: Later i use find_all for description `discription = post.find_all('p')`

Comment: Yes, but that's only searching within what `soup.find` returns.  Have you printed that to see that you're getting what you expect?

Comment: Actualy it isn't. The part of text that i need is simply not here, and I have no idea why.   I dont know why `soup.find` is not getting it with all of other text, but if you got any ideas i would be very gratefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you see on the page is stored inside `<script>` element. So to parse it you can use next example:

```py
import re
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://habr.com/ru/hubs/gamedev/articles/"  # Url to website

page = requests.get(URL).text
data = re.search(r"window\.__INITIAL_STATE__=(.*}});", page).group(1)

data = json.loads(data)

for a in sorted(
    data["articlesList"]["articlesList"].values(),
    key=lambda k: k["timePublished"],
    reverse=True,
):
    print(a["titleHtml"])
    print(BeautifulSoup(a["leadData"]["textHtml"], "html.parser").text)

    # we want just first article
    break
```

Prints:

```
30 лет DOOM: новый код — новые баги
Сегодня первой игре из серии DOOM исполняется ровно 30 лет! Мы не могли обойти стороной это событие и в честь этого решили посмотреть, как же выглядит код этой легендарной игры спустя годы.
```